# Error not thrown for SQL update

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have this simple SQL Update

```
IF(@MyID IS NOT NULL)
 BEGIN
  BEGIN TRY
   UPDATE DATATABLE
    SET Param1=@Param1, Data2=@Data2,...
    WHERE MyID=@MyID
   END TRY
   BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() AS 'Message' 
    RETURN -1
   END CATCH

   SELECT * FROM DATATABLE WHERE MyID= @@IDENTITY
   SET @ResultMessage = 'Succefully Inserted' 
   SELECT @ResultMessage AS 'Message' 
   RETURN 0
 END
```

The problem is that when I provide an invalid ID, one that does not exist it, does not throw an error I still get an error code of 0 with the Successfully inserted message. I also added this after the catch. Still nothing, am I missing something fundamental?

```
END CATCH
IF(@@ERROR != 0)
BEGIN
    SET @ResultMessage = 'Not Successful Inserted' 
    SELECT @ResultMessage AS 'Message' 
    RETURN -1
END
SELECT * FROM DATATABLE WHERE MyID= @@IDENTITY
SET @ResultMessage = 'Succefully Inserted' 
SELECT @ResultMessage AS 'Message' 
RETURN 0
```

Is there something special I am suppose to look for?

Comment: UPDATE doesnt care if the expression succeeds, otherwise you'd get an error on first row in table that doesnt match criteria

Comment: Updating 0 rows <> an exception. Also, STOP USING @@IDENTITY

Comment: @AaronBertrand Curious why can't I use @@Identity? Is it bad programming practice? I also seem to have copied that from my insert actually, in my update I do not use `@@iDENTITY`

Comment: `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` is much more reliable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL will catch errors, but an UPDATE statement that does not update any rows, is a valid SQL statement and should not return an error.   You can check **@@RowCount** to see how many rows the update statement actually updated

```
  IF(@MyID IS NOT NULL)
     BEGIN
      BEGIN TRY
       UPDATE DATATABLE
        SET Param1=@Param1, Data2=@Data2,...
        WHERE MyID=@MyID
        IF @@RowCount = 0
        BEGIN
           SELECT 'No record found...' AS Message
           RETURN -1
        END
       END TRY
       BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() AS 'Message' 
        RETURN -1
       END CATCH

       SELECT * FROM DATATABLE WHERE MyID= @@IDENTITY
       SET @ResultMessage = 'Succefully Inserted' 
       SELECT @ResultMessage AS 'Message' 
       RETURN 0
     END
```

Comment: Thanks. But I assume this means that the transaction succeeded it just did not do anything?

Comment: @JackThor well the only difference will be semantic, really, but you could begin an explicit transaction, and when @@ROWCOUNT is 0, ROLLBACK (or just raise your own exception).

Comment: @JackThor If you do a `UPDATE MyTable SET Mycolumn = 1 WHERE 1=0` it will run but no data will be changed.  Same deal here.

Comment: This code detects a successful UPDATE statement, that didn't find any records to update.....

Comment: If you really want an error you can just use RAISERROR, or THROW in the case of SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 1):

**IF @@RowCount = 0 BEGIN Select 1/0; END**

I don know if this is a good way of doing it but this is what I just did. The User gets notified with error :) if there are 0 rows affected.

```
Update Table1 Set Table1_Sold = 1 Where table1_ID = '043f258B-8A0B-4CA1-87EC-CDCBD38EE9E1';

 IF @@RowCount = 0 BEGIN Select 1/0; END
```

You get Error if there were 0 rows effected. Probably not the best way but it works for me. I may get dislikes for this.

In C# you cna catch the error and Display your own Message.

```
catch (SqlException e) 
            {


                switch(e.Number)
                 {
                    case 8134:// Divide by zero error
                        MessageBox.Show("ERROR Divide by ZERO, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        break;

                    default:
                  MessageBox.Show($"{e.Number.ToString()} \t {e.Message} \t {e.InnerException} \t {e.Data} \t {e.ToString()}", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        break;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace

```
IF(@MyID IS NOT NULL)
```

with

```
IF(@MyID IS NOT NULL) OR NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM DATATABLE
    WHERE MyID=@MyID
)
```

Or you may take Sparky's solution. Depends on what logic is more suitable for you. Should an error message be thrown or not if @MyID is not valid?

Answer (score 0):

I would so something like this .... WRAP the update statement in a Transaction and rollback on failure

```
IF(@MyID IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
   BEGIN TRY

       BEGIN TRANSACTION
           UPDATE DATATABLE
            SET Param1=@Param1, Data2=@Data2,...
            WHERE MyID=@MyID
            SET @ResultMessage = 'Succefully Inserted' 
            SELECT @ResultMessage AS 'Message' 
            RETURN 0
        COMMIT TRANSACTION 
   END TRY

   BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION  

        SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() AS 'ErrorMessage' 
        SET @ResultMessage = 'Not Successful Inserted' 
        SELECT @ResultMessage AS 'Message' 
        RETURN -1
    END CATCH
END
```